# What does gsutil cp do before it begins transferring?

Tags: gsutil

When you run gsutil cp, it will usually say something like:

```
Copying s3://your_bucket/your_file [Content-Type=binary/octet-stream]...
```

At that time the CPU becomes busy with the process for a while before its weight is put on the network.

My question is: what is gsutil doing that takes CPU time before it starts the transfer?

Comment: Can you say more about what command you're running when this happens? gsutil performs different operations depending on whether you're uploading small vs large files, copying in they cloud, copying across providers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the arguments you use, it will check for existing files on the destination, calculate md5 checksums for source and destination files. Look and see if an upload needs resuming, calculate md5 checksums for file parts and so on.